# Reviews showing on the reviewer's own profile page instead of the profile that it was written on

Tags: django, review

I am adding a simple review function on my Social platform Django project, where Users can write a review on another user's profile. But after posting the review, it's only showing on the profile page of the user that I'm currently signed in to.

This is my models.py

```
  ` class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reviewmsg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reviewmsg)`
```

views.py

```
  ` def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    reviews = user.review_set.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        review = Review.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            reviewmsg=request.POST.get('reviewmsg')
        )
        return redirect('user-profile', pk=user.id)

    context = {'user':user, 'rooms':rooms, 'reviews':reviews}
    return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', context)`
```

excerpt from my profile page template

```
  ` <div>
    {% for review in reviews %}
    <div class="comment-sect" style="margin-top: 0.5rem;">

    <div class="comment-photo" style="margin: auto;">
    <a href="{% url 'user-profile' review.user.id %}">
    <div class="profile-photo">
    <img src="{{review.user.avatar.url}}">
    </div>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="comment-info" style="width: 300px;">

    <small>@{{review.user}}</small>
    <small>{{review.created|timesince}} ago </small>

    <p style="margin-bottom:0;">{{review.reviewmsg}}</p>


    </div>

    </div><!--end of comment-sect-->


    {% endfor %}


    <div class="comment-form" style="margin-top: 0.5rem; text-align:center;">
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div>Submit a Review
    <input type="text" name="reviewmsg" placeholder="What do you think about this User?"/>
     
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>`
```

EDITED
As mentioned by @lain Shelvington, I agree that I need to add another ForeignKey to my models. I tried updating the models.py to:

```
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
 class Review(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     reviewmsg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.reviewmsg)
```

and views.py to:

```
         user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
         rooms = user.room_set.all()
         reviews = user.review_set.all()
     
         if request.method == 'POST':
             review = Review.objects.create(
                 user=request.user,
                 profile=user,
                 reviewmsg=request.POST.get('reviewmsg')
             )
             return redirect('user-profile', pk=user.id)

         context = {'user':user, 'rooms':rooms, 'reviews':reviews}
         return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', context)
```

but ended up with error:

> ValueError at /profile/7/
> Cannot assign "<User: celeste>": "Review.profile" must be a "Profile" instance

Comment: Your Review model needs two ForeignKeys to User, one for the user posting the review and one for the user being reviewed

Comment: because you saving review with the user as the logged in(the one writing review) user `user=request.user,`  change the create method to `user=user,` instead

Comment: @lain I figure that's what I missed. Can you give me an idea on what to input in the other ForeignKey? As you can see, I already have the one for the user that wish to post a review. I am lost as to what should the other model contain since it will use the User model as well.

Comment: @ian where did the Profile model come from, can you add it? It's not clear if the review should be related to the User model or Profile model

Comment: Oh I missed the upper part, my bad. I added a Profile model on the models.py:

`class Profile(models.Model):                                   
user = models.ForeignKey (User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`